# Programmatically Connect/Disconnect HDMI

Tags: android, usb, hdmi

I want to programmatically connect & disconnect HDMI. I'm able to get the status of the HDMI using the below command,

```
/sys/class/switch/hdmi/state
```

Answer (score 0):

Since HDMI is a physical adapter, you would not be able to connect or disconnecting it programmatically.  Are you trying to enable & disable the connection programmatically?

Comment: Yes, i want to enable & disable the connection programatically

Comment: @John how we can enable disble can you share some command or anything other?

Answer (score 0):

I bought cable for c port of android to connect to TV hdmi

It works on most apps an programs

Th e nfl app it does not work.  A message   FL video may not be cast

The programmed of app has disabled right?

Can i re-enable